# Need help identifying this SMD component

Tags: surface-mount

Does anyone know what this is? It's an SMD taken from a Citroen 2.0 BlueHDi AdBlue ECU that's faulty.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/YZZN9.jpg! [the mosfet is to
Top left above Q111. The TVS is the big SMD next to D100]

Comment: looks kind of like a capacitor.

Comment: Get one from a car junk yard

Comment: https://www.ebay.ie/sch/i.html?_from=R40&_trksid=p2334524.m570.l1313&_nkw=adblue+citroen+ecu&_sacat=61525&LH_TitleDesc=0&Brand=VW%2520%2528Genuine%2520OE%2529&_osacat=61525&_odkw=adblue

Comment: Transzorb maybe? If that has failed, then there may be other problems.

Comment: This is a TVS. Datasheet: https://www.diodes.com/assets/Datasheets/ds19002.pdf . Looking the marking code on page 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the replies. Indeed it was a TVS SMBJ36(C)A.

Comment: PIX ELS - Hi, Thanks for coming back with the answer to your question. In order to mark the topic as solved, please "accept" your answer (click the "tick mark" next to your answer, to turn it green). Then it is shown as having an accepted answer in various lists, and we don't get nagged for it being a question with an unaccepted answer. Thanks!